# Delete document by _id doesn't work

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a script that store Data in a MongoDB, and I'd like to delete document with another script.
Each document stored in my DB comes in this format :

```
{"k1526346000_500": 
      {"r45037": {"C": "1", "V": "1000", "L": "1181", "D": "75"},
      {"r21542": {"C": "2", "V": "94527", "L": "105", "D": "94"},
      etc...
}
```

What I'd like to do is to delete a document by passing the key (k1526346000_500 in this case)
When I try to do :

```
db.collection.delete_one({_id:key})
```

Where key corresponds to k1526346000_500, I have an error :

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
   self.run()
   File "fetch.py", line 38, in run
       read(self.mongo).test(key)
       File "/var/python/lib/script.py", line 121, in test
       db.collection.delete_one({_id:key})
   NameError: global name '_id' is not defined
```

BUT, the document is correctly deleted.
It's a problem for me because the error exits the script, and I have to make it run in an loop.

Do you know how can I make it work ?

Thanks ;)

EDIT : When I dump that document, I have this result :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5afda3efb2031025afe0d32e"), "k1526346000_500" : { "r4" : { "C" : "1", "V" : "447616", "L" : "1", "D" : "4" }
```

So this is definitely not "_id" to use here, but I don't know how to catch this field :(

Comment: First I generated all the lines like : {"r45037": {"C":.......

Then I created a dict like that : 

dict['k1526346000_500'] = rows where rows is already a dict.
So I assumed that when I created that key, it goes directly in '_id' doesn't it ?

Edit : If it's not an "_id" field, what it could be ?

Comment: You're right mate, here's the result :

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5afda3efb2031025afe0d32e"), "k1526346000_500" : { "r4" : { "C" : "1", "V" : "447616", "L" : "1", "D" : "4" }, "r5" : { "C" : "1", "V" : "398949", "L" : "1", "D" : "5" }, "r6" : { "C" : "1", "V" : "9276983", "L" : "1", "D" : "6" }, "r7" : { "C" : "1", "V" : "1544083", "L" : "1", "D" : "7" }, "r0" : { "C" : "1", "V" : "471757766", "L" : "1", "D" : "0" }, "r1" : { "C" : "1", "V" : "3473966", "L" : "1", "D" : "1" }, "r2" : { "C" : "1", "V" : "3396966", "L" : "1", "D" : "2" }}

So how can I call this ?

Answer (score 0):

Python is not JavaScript. Keys need to be quoted:

```
db.collection.delete_one({"_id": key})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer !

I didn't say it but I tested this, and I don't have any error, but the document isn't removed

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually specifying the name of the collection?  Eg if your collection is called `tree`, you need to say

`db.tree.deleteOne({_id:key})`

Also make sure you are connected to the correct database- eg, `use forest`.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for your answer.

I actually specify the name of the collection, I just replaced it here.

I make several actions before trying to delete, and all those actions work, so the parameters passed are right !

Answer (score 0):

`"k1526346000_500"` is the name of a field within the document, not the document's `_id` value. So assuming that's a unique key name, you can remove that document by searching for it with the [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/#op._S_exists) operator:

```
db.collection.delete_one({key: {"$exists": True}})
```